# Need help in jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a list of items, where items are chosen based on the press of a button. They then show up within a table (list-table) with a remove button. For some reason, I cannot get the click function associated with the remove button to work. When the button is clicked, it should log "works" to the console, but nothing happens. Any help/tips are appreciated! Thanks!

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function(event) {
    var foodItem = $(this).text();
    foodItem = foodItem.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') == true){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('#' + foodItem).remove();
        var itemIndex = groceryListArray.indexOf(foodItem)
        groceryListArray.splice(itemIndex,1)
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var newRow = '<tr id = ' + foodItem +'><td id="col-md-1"></td><td>' + foodItem + '</td><td class="remove"><div class="btn remove">Remove?</div></td></tr>';
        $(newRow).appendTo($('#list-table'));
        groceryListArray.push(foodItem)
    }
});
//When an item is removed from the table via the remove? button
$('.remove').click(function() {
    console.log("works");
});
```

Comment: That's because the event handler for the remove button is bound before there is a remove button present, and `$('.remove')` only gets the elements present in the DOM at the time it's ran, not elements added later, for that you'll need delegated event handlers.

Comment: [**Understanding Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: look into `.on` instead of click. something like `$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){ ... });` would work. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Put that `click` event right after `$(newRow).appendTo($('#list-table'))` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason remove isn't working is because your are attaching the click handler to `$('.remove')` but the remove buttons do not yet exist. Your remove buttons are being created after your `$('.btn-primary)` object is clicked.

Attach the click handler to the table (assuming it already exists) that will contain your food item rows, using your remove buttons as a selector.

```
$('table').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    console.log("works");
});
```